# How change the home folder of an installation using enviromental variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to install a program called Apache Airflow.

The instructions show how to specify a home folder

```
# airflow needs a home, ~/airflow is the default,
# but you can lay foundation somewhere else if you prefer
# (optional)
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

# install from pypi using pip
pip install apache-airflow

# initialize the database
airflow initdb
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html

I am working in Google Colab, and I want the folder to be in the home directory, which is `/content` . However, no matter what I specify for `export AIRFLOW_HOME=` , the home folder is always set in `/root`.

What I have tried so far

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~content

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~content/

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/content

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/content/airflow

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/content/airflow/

export AIRFLOW_HOME='pwd' 

export AIRFLOW_HOME='pwd' /content/

export AIRFLOW_HOME='pwd' /content

export AIRFLOW_HOME='pwd' content/

export AIRFLOW_HOME='pwd' content
```

For convenience, here's a colab notebook of the code for easy tinker

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lV-D60qEJN2F4azUYTDVeUCKv6qTyzL3

Comment: Have you checked the value of the variable using `echo $AIRFLOW`?

Comment: I'm trying it after each variation on `export AIRFLOW_HOME` but none of them is giving an output, so it looks like the environmental variable is not even being set somehow

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes?

Comment: I'm trying several variations on that, such as "~/content" , I'm still not getting an output for echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable with python:

```
import os
os.environ[“AIRFLOW_HOME”] = “/content”
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set your environment as below in your present working directory.

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME="$(pwd)"
```

For example if your `pwd` is `/opt` in root then you can `cd` to `/opt` and run above. When you run `airflow initdb` the `airflow.cfg` file and others will be located in this directory but if you want to have these files in separate `airflow` folder then before running above export statement you can create airflow directory (`mkdir airflow`) and `cd` to the folder and then run above export command.